# How do I get the top N percent rows of data in a table in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have googled this, but all I found is the SQL Server or MySQL syntax like
`SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT * FROM SOME_TABLE`, etc.
That will not work in Oracle. So can someone tell me the right syntax?

I read the documentation on `CUME_DIST()` and `PERCENT_RANK()` but I don't think they work the way I think they work and they have nothing to do with what I mean here.

Anyway, I know how to fetch the top N rows of data from a table, but I don't know how to do that if I have to fetch the N percent one.

Comment: for single table use sample clause

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to 12c, it's built into the SQL engine now.

select * from hr.employees
fetch first 10 percent Rows only;

[Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABBADDD)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order by` and `rownum`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over () as cnt
      from table t
      order by <whatever>
     ) t
where rownum <= 0.1 * cnt;
```

Well, if you are going to use analytic functions, you can also do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over () as cnt,
             row_number() over (order by <whatever>) as seqnum
      from table t
      order by <whatever>
     ) t
where seqnum <= 0.1 * cnt;
```

Note:  This ignores ties.  If you want to handle ties, you can use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.